# Jquery syncrounous issues

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jfeed

Ok so I have a basic function that get's 2 feeds. My issue is that the function, running asynchronously skips down to the alert function(in for testing) before it's doing the function to get both feeds. I'm sure there's a viable solution but it has me scratching my head. here's the script. I'd greatly appreciate the help, thanks!

```
function getFeeds(){
    jQuery.getFeed({
        url: 'proxy.php?url='+feed1,
        success: function(feed) {       

            for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 10; i++) {

                var item = feed.items[i];

                s_string += '<div class = \"cont_div a'+i+'\"><h2>'
             /*   + '<a href="'
                + item.link
                + '">'*/
                + item.title
                /*+ '</a>'*/
                + '</h2></div>';

               /* html += '<div class="updated">'
                + item.updated
                + '</div>';

                html += '<div>'
                + item.description
                + '</div>';*/
            }

        }  
    });    
    jQuery.getFeed({
        url: 'proxy.php?url='+feed2,
        success: function(feed) {       

            for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 10; i++) {

                var item = feed.items[i];

                s_string += '<div class = \"cont_div a'+i+'\"><h2>'
             /*   + '<a href="'
                + item.link
                + '">'*/
                + item.title
                /*+ '</a>'*/
                + '</h2></div>';

               /* html += '<div class="updated">'
                + item.updated
                + '</div>';

                html += '<div>'
                + item.description
                + '</div>';*/
            }


       } 
    });    
alert(s_string);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the two requests as separate timelines:

1. create two variables for success indicators
2. put a check inside of the callbacks
3. which request finishes last would do your finished_callback

The code is something like this:

```
function getFeeds(finished_callback) {
    var feed_a_finished = false,
        feed_b_finished = false,
        s_string = "";

    jQuery.getFeed( {
        url: 'proxy.php?url='+feed1,
        success: function(feed) {
            /* Your code ... */
            feed_a_finished = true;
            if (feed_a_finished && feed_b_finished) {
                finished_callback();
            }
        }  
    });
    feed_b_finished = false; 
    jQuery.getFeed({
        url: 'proxy.php?url='+feed2,
        success: function(feed) {       
            /* Your code ... */
            feed_b_finished = true;
            if (feed_a_finished && feed_b_finished) {
                finished_callback();
            }
        } 
    });
}

getFeeds(function () {
    alert(s_string);
});
```